# posting an html with images, css, and javascript in node.js Express 4

Tags: html, css, express, pug

I can use

```
res.sendFile(BASEDIR + '/public/html/info.html');
```

to post this html. How do I display the html if it has images, css and javascripts that are included in the page. 
My view engine is jade.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `express.static` middleware for serving static HTML / CSS / JS,

EXAMPLE:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');

var server = express();

server.use(express.static(__dirname + '/www'));
server.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'www')));
server.get('*', function (request, response) {
  response.sendFile(__dirname + '/www/404.html');
});

server.listen(80);
```

This will serve any static file under `www` folder, including HTML, JS and CSS files, and the rest (non existing files) will be catched by `*` which shows the 404